# Stop the carousel from looping manually as well as automatically when boundaries are reached

Tags: html, css

Stop the carousel from looping manually as well as automatically when boundries are reached

I have 3 tabs designed from the bootstrap carousel. The Previous and Next will take to prev and next steps respectively. But after Step 3 it should not go back to Step1 when the next is clicked.

Which means it must stop at boundaries.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<style>
.carousel-indicators {
  display: flex!important;
  position: inherit!important;
  justify-content: space-between!important;
}

.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {flex: 1 0 auto!important;} 
.carousel-indicators {  margin-left: auto!important;  margin-right: auto!important;}


.carousel-indicators .active {
 border-bottom: blue 5px solid!important;
}

.page{
    height:50px!important;
    background:#efefef!important;
    margin:0px!important;
}
</style>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">

        <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-interval="false">

          <div class="carousel-indicators">



            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="page active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">Step1</div>
            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" class="page" aria-label="Slide 2">Step2</div>
            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" class="page" aria-label="Slide 3">Step3</div>




          </div>

          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-wrap="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p class="d-block w-100">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.



                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.



                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="">Previous</span>
          </button>
            <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">

            <span class="">Next</span>
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi ! As far as I can see you have not changed a thing - it's just the default behavior of the carousel. What have you tried so far? Does the documentation say anything about this? Do you want us to implement it for you? That would not be very common here - please develop yourself and we'll help debug.

Comment: I am a newbie and dont know how to do that. I have managed to build so much myself.

Comment: That is all the more reason to go through its documentation. Maybe there is just a configuration you can set at the start. There could also be a support forum with people who already know that or an example in the docs for exactly this. Make some effort.

Comment: add `data-bs-wrap="false"` to `#carouselExampleControls` to stop it from going to first slide when clicking next on the last slide.

Comment: @Ralph this didnt help!